# Error 403 when trying to push with AWS code commit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I just finished setting up code commit, but when I try to push my code I'm getting this error:

```
Username for 'https://git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com': rabbitsnap
Password for 'https://rabbitsnap@git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com': 
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/reposrabbitsnap/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What could be wrong?

I'm pretty sure my password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by following this [blog](https://weonlymeetondreams.blogspot.com/2022/09/adding-aws-code-commit-to-existing.html).

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).